# Does NNpack are implemented in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Does NNpack are implemented in tensorflow? I find that it can be  to be leveraged by higher-level frameworks, such as Torch, Caffe, Tensorflow, Theano, and Mocha.jl, Howerver, I have not found any implementation in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow does not currently use [NNPACK](https://github.com/Maratyszcza/NNPACK) to accelerate its math kernels; instead it uses a combination of [Eigen::Tensor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support), [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn), [cuBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/), [XLA-generated](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/), and hand-written kernels.

If you wanted to use NNPACK inside a TensorFlow op, you could do this by [adding a custom op kernel](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) that used that library.